# Save State of a Multiple choice ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-listview, sharedpreferences

Can someone instruct me how  to save the state of the checkbox's of a multiple choice listview? i'm trying to save the state into a database but it could also be done using shared preferences, i think.

my regards.

Comment: What is your actual problem?  Using Shared Prefs is a fine idea - what else do you need to know?

Comment: Hi Haphazard and thanks for your attention. What i need to know is how to save the state of the checkbox into the database. SQLite doesnt have boolean compatibility. Could you instruct me with some tutorials. I already spent 2 months around this problem.

Comment: So the old school way is best 0 is false, not 0 is true...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two months on this problem? Yikes!

The first approach that occurs to me is to save a comma-separated text string of the checked index positions. On retrieval, you can split the string at the commas and parse the int values into an int array to recover the indexes, and then use that for whatever you need (restoring checked states, processing the checked items, whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store the booleans in the database as integers or text for that matter and just convert them in your insert/extract method?